# Missing libraries Ubuntu in windows?

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, lts, libraries

I am not a linux user, at all, but I am looking to use openFOAM a CFD software that is only linux available. i found a method to install it via installing ubuntu 18.04 LTS in windows with the windows store as a subsystem [link of windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804-lts/9n9tngvndl3q) (if that makes sens.... sorry i am not familiar with this type of things...) the thing is when trying to do some executions? i would call? from openFOAM, i get an error that from what i understand i am missing a library? maybe? dont know...
so I tryed to find help in the [OpenFOAM forum](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-installation/226321-cant-use-calc-functions-after-installation-w10.html#post767059), but i thought maybe give it a try here...
i am copying the error at the end of the post and also if any extra information is needed please dont hesitate

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUJGY.png)
in the programmer guide they speak about libraries but do not even know where to beging...[OpenFOAM documentation](https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/)

Comment: The thing that jumps out is `make: command not found` - did you install the `make` package (perhaps as a dependency of `build-essential`)?

Comment: hello! thanks for the help! i think i solve it with your comment, i installed make and also build-essential sudo apt-get install build-essential thanks!